# Reactjs : How to set navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition in cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, geolocation, setcookie

I am trying to setting getcurrentLocation in cookie on my first run.
But not able to do so.

My current cookie.js

```
export default{
    /**
   * @func persistent
   *
   * @returns {boolean} Returns true if cookies are persistent, false if not.
   */
  persistent() {
    if (navigator.cookieEnabled != null && navigator.cookieEnabled) {
      const cookieName = "dummy.cookie.data";
      const expires = new Date();
      expires.setYear(expires.getYear() + 1930); // We try to save a cookie for 30 years
      document.cookie = `${cookieName}; expires=${expires.toUTCString()}`;
  if (document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName) !== -1) {
    this.remove(cookieName);
    return true;
  }

  const userMarket = getLocation();
  document.cookie = `${cookieName}; expires=${userMarket}`;
  function getLocation() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError);
    } else {
      console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      }
  }

  function geoSuccess(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log("lat:" + lat + " lng:" + lng);
  }
  this.remove(cookieName);
}
return false;
  }
};
```

I want to add navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition to get its value .

//example

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
   (position) => {
          this.setState({
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            error: null,
          });
        },
        (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
        { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
      );
```

here how can i able to create a util function to fetch the geolocation?

Any lead will be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your example you tries to set up cookie with empty name, and this cooki was set up with blank name and `dummy.cookie.data` value.

You need to set up value too.

**Example:**

```
document.cookie = `${cookieName}=yourExampleValue; expires=${expires.toUTCString()}`;
```

Here is the [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Comment: hi Artem thank you for your answer. This code of mine is just a small bunch of code which has other line too. I want to get navigator.geolocation.currentlocation as a cookie too so what I need to add here.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar you need to handle `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` html5 api method. Here is examples: 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: could you please once check my edited code. I have added geolocation . thanks

Comment: @TanmoySarkar looks working, try to check it on browser please.

Comment: Any way to check in localhost ?

Comment: Artem here how can i able to create a util function to fetch the geolocation?